# How to sort array object after foreach lopping?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some array object below. I want to sort data by id after foreach looping, i was using `sort()` but there's error. How can i sort my data and loop sequentially?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  const data = [
    {
      id : 3,
      name: 'John'
    },
    {
      id : 1,
      name: 'Doe'
    },
    {
      id : 2,
      name: 'Lorem'
    },
  ]

  data.forEach((item, index) => {  
    item.sort(function(a, b) {
      $('.data').append(`<ul>
        <li>${item.id}</li>
      </ul>`);
    });
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="data"></div>
```

Comment: that item  is clearly an object inside your array so it's doesnt have sort function. sort array directly by data.sort((v,v2)=>v.id-v2.id)

Answer (score 0):

*View exception messages*

```
item.sort is not a function TypeError: item.sort is not a function
```

> Either convert the values you call the [sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method to an array, or make sure you only call the sort method on valid arrays

*According to the data format of your question, it is recommended that you sort first and then `forEach`.*

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  const data = [
    {id: 3, name: 'John'},
    {id: 1, name: 'Doe'},
    {id: 2, name: 'Lorem'},
  ];

  // Sorts the data array by id in ascending order
  data.sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id);
  
  // Pass in each element of the sorted array and execute the given function once
  data.forEach(({id}) => {
    $('.data').append(`<ul><li>${id}</li></ul>`);
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="data"></div>
```

*But if in fact, the data format is more complex, such as an array of multiple array elements, and each array element represents a set of li, you can refer to the following code snippet.*

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  const data = [
    [
      {id: 3, name: 'John'},
      {id: 1, name: 'Doe'},
      {id: 2, name: 'Lorem'}
    ],
    [
      {id: 2, name: 'Lorem'},
      {id: 1, name: 'Doe'},
      {id: 3, name: 'John'}
    ]
  ];

  // Sorts the data array by id in ascending order
  data.sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id);

  // Pass in each array element of the array and execute the given function once
  data.forEach(item => {
    const $ul = 
      $('<ul/>').append(
        item
          .sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id)
          .map(({id}) => $(`<li>${id}</li>`))
      );
    $('.data').append($ul);
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="data"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try sorting first then forEach() afterward:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  const data = [{
      id: 3, name: 'John'
    },
    {
      id: 1, name: 'Doe'
    },
    {
      id: 2, name: 'Lorem'
    },
  ];

  data.sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id).forEach((item) => {
    $('.data').append(`<ul>
      <li>${item.id}</li>
    </ul>`);
  });  
})
```